# How to integrate $\frac{1}{(1 + x^5)(1 + x^7)}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, rational-functions

My cousin who is in high school asked me if it is possible to integrate

$$
\int \frac{1}{(1 + x^5)(1 + x^7)} \, dx
$$

I checked the list of integrals of rational functions on Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_rational_functions)
and it doesn't seem to be here.

Is this not possible to do using elementary functions?
Wolfram Alpha can do this but the answer is extremely complicated.

Comment: I think it cannot be evaluable in terms of simple elementary functions.

Comment: This can be integrated if you're really willing to do it, by writing $(1+x^5)$ and $(1+x^7)$ as $$(x-\alpha).(x-\beta)..$$ and so on where $\alpha,\beta$ are their complex roots and then apply partial fractions.

Comment: Yes, there is a technique, but it is  gonna get ugly. Partial fractions is the technique, but it will admittedly be a mess.

Comment: It is possible, but it becomes very complicated. If you want to do it by hand, you need to factorise the denominator into first- and second degree polynomials, and use partial fractions.

Comment: If you consider the roots of $1+x^n=0$, then the denominator is "just" the product of twelve terms $\prod_{i=1}^{12}(x-a_i)$ and then partial fraction decomposition. Are you sure that your cousin is a friend ?

Comment: Wolfram alpha ends up with a formula involving logarithms of complex values, which is not going to be fun, but is essentially what happens when you do these sorts of integrals.

Comment: But in 10 of them $a_i$ will be complex numbers.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. I suppose that *a mess* is an understatement in your mind. Cheers.

Comment: @kmitov Your point is? :) You can do these integrals when $a_i$ is complex.

Comment: @kmitov The complex ones pair up two-and-two to make real, second-degree polynomials.

Comment: The complex numbers are pairs of conjugate complex numbers and it is possible to get quadratic factors with real coefficients.

Comment: $x^5=-1$ has the following five roots $x_k=(\cos\frac{\pi+2k \pi}{5}+i\sin\frac{\pi+2k \pi}{5})$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4$

Comment: $x^7=-1$ has the following seven roots $x_k=(\cos\frac{\pi+2k \pi}{7}+i\sin\frac{\pi+2k \pi}{7})$ for $k=0,1,2,3,4,5,6$

Comment: Or you can just reduce to the quadratics $x^2-2\cos((2k+1)\pi/7)x+1$. Then you end up with a lot of arctans.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solve:

$$\begin{align}\frac{1}{(x^5+1)(x^7+1)} & =\frac{a_0}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{a_1}{x+1}\\
&\quad+\frac{a_2x+b_2}{x^2-2\cos(\pi/5)x +1}\\&+\frac{a_3x+b_3}{x^2-2\cos(3\pi/5)x+1}\\
&\quad+\frac{a_4x+b_4}{x^2-2\cos(\pi/7)x +1}\\
&\quad+\frac{a_5x+b_5}{x^2-2\cos(3\pi/7)x +1}\\
&\quad+\frac{a_6x+b_6}{x^2-2\cos(5\pi/7)x +1}\\
\end{align}$$

Then you can use basic integrals to solve each:

$$\int \frac{ax+b}{x^2-2cx+1}\,dx$$

You'll get lots of logarithms and arctans, and it will be just horrible. And that doesn't even count how horrible the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are going to be.

Answer (score 2):

Using the substitution by [Thomas Andrews](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7933/thomas-andrews):
$$x = -y$$
$$\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^5+1)(x^7+1)}dx = -\int\dfrac{dy}{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)}$$ 
Looking for expansion in the form:
$$\dfrac1{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)} = \dfrac A{(y-1)^2} + \dfrac B{y-1} $$
$$+ \sum_{k=1}^2\left(\dfrac{C_k}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}{5}\right)}+\dfrac{C_{-k}}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{-2\pi ki}{5}\right)}\right)$$
$$+ \sum_{k=1}^3\left(\dfrac{D_k}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}{7}\right)}+\dfrac{D_{-k}}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{-2\pi ki}{7}\right)}\right).$$

Notice, that:
$$y^5-1 = (y-1)P_4(y),\quad y^7-1 = (y-1)P_6(y),$$
where
$$P_4(y) = y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1,$$
$$P_6(y) = y^6 + y^5 + y^4 + y^3 + y^2 + y + 1,$$
$$P_4'(y) = 4y^3 + 3y^2 + 2y + 1,$$
$$P_6'(y) = 6y^5 + 5y^4 + 4y^3 + 3y^2 + 2y + 1.$$

Finding the coefficients.
$$A = \lim_{y\to1}\dfrac{(y-1)^2}{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)} = \dfrac1{P_4(1)P_6(1))} = \dfrac1{35}.$$
$$B = \lim_{y\to1}(y-1)\left(\dfrac1{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)}-\dfrac A{(y-1)^2}\right) = \lim_{y\to-1}\dfrac{1-A\cdot P_4(y)P_6(y)}{(y-1)P_4(y)P_6(y)}.$$
Using the L'Hospital's Rule:
$$B=-A\dfrac{P_4'(1)P_6(1) + P_4(1)P_6'(1)}{P_4(1)P_6(1)} = -\dfrac1{35}\dfrac{10\cdot7 + 5\cdot21}{5\cdot7} = -\dfrac17.$$
$$C_k = \lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}5}\dfrac{y -\exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}5}{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)} = \lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}5}\dfrac{y -\exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}5}{y^5-1}\lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}5}\dfrac1{y^7-1}.$$
Using the L'Hospital's Rule:
$$C_k = \lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}5}\dfrac{1}{5y^4(y^7-1)} = \dfrac{1}{5\exp\dfrac{8\pi ki}5\left(\exp\dfrac{14\pi ki}5-1\right)} = \dfrac{1}{10i\exp\dfrac{15\pi ki}5\sin\dfrac{7\pi k}5},$$
$$C_k = \dfrac{(-1)^k}{10i\sin\dfrac{7\pi k}5}.$$
$$D_k = \lim_{y\to\exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}7}\dfrac{y -\exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}7}{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)} = \lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}7}\dfrac{y -\exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}7}{y^7-1}\lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}7}\dfrac1{y^5-1}.$$
Using the L'Hospital's Rule:
$$D_k = \lim_{y\to \exp\dfrac{2\pi ki}7}\dfrac{1}{7y^6(y^5-1)} = \dfrac{1}{7\exp\dfrac{12\pi ki}7\left(\exp\dfrac{10\pi ki}7-1\right)} = \dfrac{1}{14i\exp\dfrac{17\pi ki}7\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7},$$
$$D_k = \dfrac{\exp\left(-\dfrac{3\pi ki}7\right)}{14i\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}.$$
Then,
$$\dfrac{C_k}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}{5}\right)}+\dfrac{C_{-k}}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{-2\pi ki}{5}\right)}
$$
$$= \dfrac{(-1)^k}{10i\sin{\dfrac{7\pi k}5}}\cdot\left(\dfrac1{y -\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}{5}\right)} - \dfrac1{y-\exp\left(-\dfrac{2\pi ki}{5}\right)}\right) $$
$$ = \dfrac{(-1)^k}{10i\sin{\dfrac{7\pi k}5}}\cdot\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}{5}\right)- \exp\left(-\dfrac{2\pi ki}{5}\right)}{\left(y - \cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}\right)^2 + \sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}}$$
$$ = \dfrac{(-1)^k}{5\sin{\dfrac{7\pi k}5}}\cdot\dfrac{\sin{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}}{\left(y - \cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}\right)^2 + \sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}},$$
$$\dfrac{D_k}{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)}+\dfrac{D_{-k}}{y-\exp\left(-\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)} = $$ 
$$ = \dfrac{\cos\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14i\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\left(\dfrac1{x-\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)}-\dfrac1{y-\exp\left(-\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)}\right)$$ 
$$ -\, \dfrac{i\sin\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14i\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\left(\dfrac1{y-\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)}+\dfrac1{y-\exp\left(-\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)}\right)$$ 
$$ = \dfrac{\cos\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14i\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\cdot\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)-\exp\left(-\dfrac{2\pi ki}7\right)}{\left(y - \cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}\right)^2 + \sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}}$$ 
$$ -\, \dfrac{\sin\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\cdot\dfrac{2\left(y-\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}\right)}{y^2 - 2y\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7} + 1}$$ 
$$ = \dfrac{\cos\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{7\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\cdot\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{2\pi k}7}{\left(y - \cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}\right)^2 + \sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}}$$
$$+ \dfrac{\sin\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\cdot\dfrac{2\left(y-\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}\right)}{y^2 - 2y\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7} + 1}.$$

So,
$$\int\dfrac{dy}{(y^5-1)(y^7-1)} = \dfrac1{35}\int\dfrac{dy}{(y-1)^2} - \dfrac17\int\dfrac{dy}{y-1} $$$$ + \sum_{k=1}^2\dfrac{(-1)^k}{5\sin{\dfrac{7\pi k}5}}\int\dfrac{\sin{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}}{\left(y - \cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}\right)^2 + \sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi k}5}}\,dy$$
$$+\sum_{k=1}^3\dfrac{\cos\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{7\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\int\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{2\pi k}7}{\left(y - \cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}\right)^2 + \sin^2{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}}\,dy$$
$${+ \sum_{k=1}^3\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\int\dfrac{2\left(y-\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7}\right)}{y^2 - 2y\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7} + 1}\,dy}$$
$$= -\dfrac1{35}\dfrac1{y-1} - \dfrac17\ln|y-1| + \sum_{k=1}^2\dfrac{(-1)^k}{5\sin\dfrac{7\pi k}5}\arctan\dfrac{y - \cos\dfrac{2\pi k}5}{\sin\dfrac{2\pi k}5}$$
$$+\sum_{k=1}^3\dfrac{\cos\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{7\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\arctan\dfrac{y - \cos\dfrac{2\pi k}7}{\sin\dfrac{2\pi k}7}$$
$$+ \sum_{k=1}^3\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\ln\left(y^2 - 2y\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7} + 1\right) + const.$$
Thus
$$\boxed{\int\dfrac{dx}{(x^5+1)(x^7+1)} = \dfrac1{35}\dfrac1{x+1} + \dfrac17\ln|x+1| + \sum_{k=1}^2\dfrac{(-1)^k}{5\sin\dfrac{7\pi k}5}\arctan\dfrac{x+ \cos\dfrac{2\pi k}5}{\sin\dfrac{2\pi k}5}+\sum_{k=1}^3\dfrac{\cos\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{7\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\arctan\dfrac{x + \cos\dfrac{2\pi k}7}{\sin\dfrac{2\pi k}7} - \sum_{k=1}^3\dfrac{\sin\dfrac{3\pi k}7}{14\sin\dfrac{5\pi k}7}\ln\left(x^2 + 2x\cos{\dfrac{2\pi k}7} + 1\right) + const}.$$

Comment: You've got the wrong roots for $x^7+1=0$ and $x^5+1=0$. You have the roots for $x^7-1=0$ and $x^5-1=0$.

Comment: you're right, I'll correct them

Comment: It's probably (slightly) easier to integrate $f(x)=\frac{1}{(x^5-1)(x^7-1)}$ anyway, then note that $f(-x)=\frac{1}{(x^5+1)(x^7+1)}$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews You're too right... Thank you for hint!

Comment: @Thomas Andrews Ready

Comment: You don't actually think I'm gonna read that, do you? :) As I said in my answer, the result is a nightmare. You've still got a $y^5+1$ there early on, though. I realize that's just a remnant, and not an error.

Comment: And if you really want to be obtuse, you can substitute exact values for $\sin m\pi/5, \cos m\pi/5$. But that way leads to madness.

Comment: I just wondered to what extent is it possible to obtain a closed answer on terms and expressions, without going to the extensive system of equations for unknown coefficients. And, in my opinion, it was possible not to wake the sleeping dragon.

Comment: You can solve my way without using extensive linear equations, too, because the $a_i,b_i$ pairs are real, so, for example: $$a_2e^{i\pi/5}+b_2 = \lim_{x\to e^{i\pi/5}}\frac{x^2-2\cos(\pi/5)x+1}{(x^5+1)(x^7+1)}$$is computable with L'Hopital, and you find $a_2,b_2$ from there using that that $a_2\sin \pi/5$ is the imaginary part of the result and then determine $b_2$ from that.

Comment: in your answer that no, dares to supplement?